# Azure TimerTrigger not firing

Tags: c#, azure, timer, azure-functions, azure-function-app-proxy

This `TimerTrigger` is not firing, can someone suggest better here.

```
public async Task test([TimerTrigger("0 0 11,12 * * 1-5")] TimerInfo timer)
{
    try 
    {
        await methodname();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        _logger.LogError(null, ex.Message, "test");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you missing `[FunctionName(<<your function name here>>)]` attribute?

Comment: not really required, coz my code in visual studio. below code working fine.            
        public async Task Notification([TimerTrigger("0 30 20 * * 1-5")] TimerInfo timer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public async Task Notification([TimerTrigger("0 30 20 * * 1-5")] TimerInfo timer)
    {
        try
        {
            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is no additional configuration, you need to use `public async Task Run`. Changing `test` to `Run` may solve your problem.

As `user1672994` mentioned in the comments, it seems that you also lack the configuration of function name:

```
[FunctionName(<<your function name here>>)]
```

Comment: on my answer i tried to keep two timings in same method but unfornately dual time not firing properly, so kept two TimerTrigger methods.